# Elastic Schema Error - Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch version 2.1.1. When I try to create schema with the following payload, it gives Unsupported Parameters error:

```
URL : http://localhost:9200/enron/mails/_mapping
Operation: PUT
Payload:
    {
      "enron": {
        "properties": {
          "message_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "store": "yes"
          },
          "from": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "store": "yes"
          },
          "to": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "store": "yes",
            "multi_field": "yes"
          },
          "x_cc": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "store": "yes",
            "multi_field": "yes"
          },
          "x_bcc": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "store": "yes",
            "multi_field": "yes"
          },
          "date": {
            "type": "date",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "store": "yes"
          },
          "subject": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "analyzed",
            "store": "yes"
          },
          "body": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "analyzed",
            "store": "yes"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The error message:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "root_cause": [
          {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [enron : {properties={message_id={type=string, index=not_analyzed, store=yes}, from={type=string, index=not_analyzed, store=yes}, to={type=string, index=not_analyzed, store=yes, multi_field=yes}, x_cc={type=string, index=not_analyzed, store=yes, multi_field=yes}, x_bcc={type=string, index=not_analyzed, store=yes, multi_field=yes}, date={type=date, index=not_analyzed, store=yes}, subject={type=string, index=analyzed, store=yes}, body={type=string, index=analyzed, store=yes}}}]"
          }
        ],
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [enron : {properties={message_id={type=string, index=not_analyzed, store=yes}, from={type=string, index=not_analyzed, store=yes}, to={type=string, index=not_analyzed, store=yes, multi_field=yes}, x_cc={type=string, index=not_analyzed, store=yes, multi_field=yes}, x_bcc={type=string, index=not_analyzed, store=yes, multi_field=yes}, date={type=date, index=not_analyzed, store=yes}, subject={type=string, index=analyzed, store=yes}, body={type=string, index=analyzed, store=yes}}}]"
      },
      "status": 400
    }
```

Can some one please help me identify the error here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are couple of problems with this. You need to remove index name `enron` from payload. There is no [multi_field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) in ES 2.1. You can refer to [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) for more info

This will work

```
PUT enron/mails/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "message_id": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "store": "yes"
    },
    "from": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "store": "yes"
    },
    "to": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "store": "yes"
    },
    "x_cc": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "store": "yes"
    },
    "x_bcc": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "store": "yes"
    },
    "date": {
      "type": "date",
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "store": "yes"
    },
    "subject": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "analyzed",
      "store": "yes"
    },
    "body": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "analyzed",
      "store": "yes"
    }
  }
}
```